# How can I access an element inside of a Javascript with Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium

There is an element inside of a javascript file, hence if it's executed an element (class) will appear on-site. How am I able to find an element inside the javascript file with Selenium?

```
<body>
#...
    <script src="../public/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
#...
</body>
```

That's the output of the `driver.page_source`

I saw that there is an element inside of the .js as I inspected it locally within my Google Chrome browser. Though how am I able to access it with Selenium?

Comment: Sometimes I don't get the downvotes on this side.. I checked whether this is a duplicate - the question is well-founded and justified. Instead of disliking (if it's too easy) someone might as well leave a constructive comment.

Comment: With the script tag that has a `src=...`, you can then make selenium go to that page (or just use `requests` and send a GET request to it). From there you can go about parsing the javascript and finding what you need.

Comment: Just a note of why you may of got that downvote, people like to not receive questions that they deem to be to easy or simple. now we need to understand there is a wide range of abilities on this site so if you feel your question may be able to be found on a quick google search try to explain how/why you found everything else online unhelpful or not applicable in your question. Hope that helps for your future on Stack Overflow

Comment: @EzrielMag It's a `<script>` tag to render _Javascript_ not an element as such. What are trying to do?

Comment: Are you asking how to: (1) extract the name of the JS file from the `<script>` tag shown in your question; and then (2) access the contents of that JS file; and then (3) extract a fragment of HTML, which is (somehow) contained in (or perhaps referenced by) that JS file? And you would like to do all of this using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

there are three ways to find an element inside .js while in selenium

1. `isDisplayed()`
   The isDisplayed method in Selenium verifies if a certain element is present and displayed. If the element is displayed, then the value returned is true. If not, then the value returned is false.

The code below verifies if an element with the id attribute value next is displayed.

Syntax:

```
boolean eleSelected= driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).isDisplayed();
```

2. `isSelected()`
   This method is often used on radio buttons, checkboxes or options in a menu. It is used to determine is an element is selected. If the specified element is selected, the value returned is true. If not, the value returned is false.

The code below verifies if an element with the id attribute value PersistentCookie is displayed.

Syntax:

```
boolean elePresent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).isSelected();
```

3. `isEnabled()`
   This method verifies if an element is enabled. If the element is enabled, it returns a true value. If not, it returns a false value.

The code below verifies if an element with the id attribute value next is enabled.

Syntax:

```
boolean eleEnabled= driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).isEnabled();
```